# Python Unable to find the csv filename starting with res_

Tags: python

I am trying to read csv file named res_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv. But I am getting below error

```
Rapid> c:/Data/Rapid/.venv/py3.9.0/Scripts/python.exe "c:/Data/Rapid/Experiences/Coding/Python/Hands-On/06.Python Crash Course/11.csv.py"        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Data\Rapid\Experiences\Coding\Python\Hands-On\06.Python Crash Course\11.csv.py", line 7, 
in <module>
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Data\\Rapid\\py_resources\res_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv'
```

But Surprisingly program execution is success after renamed to **data_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv**

Comment: You have a mixture of double and single slashes in the filepath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on your error, there is only one `\` before your file name, when the other separation are `\\`.

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Data\\Rapid\\py_resources\res_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv'
```

It is not working because \r is a special character. You should use this path to access your file (`\\` in stead of `\`) :

```
'C:\\Data\\Rapid\\py_resources\\res_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv'
```

It is working with data_sitka_weather_2018_full.csv because \d is not a special character.